Very slow upload speeds From FileZilla to server
I have a Debian server running OpenSSH that I'm finding I get very slow uploads to using SFTP with FileZilla.  speedtest.net shows I have about a 20Mbps upload speed but when I upload 2 files simultaneously with FileZilla I get about 90KiB/s for each.  My ping latency to the server seems to average 133ms.  Is there anything I can do to speed it up?

Find another ISP? Perhaps they have an overloaded network & prioritise any traffic to the speed test sites.

I really doubt it's my ISP.  Seems more likely to be latency combined with SFTP just being slow as hell to transfer files.  Anyway, some kind of diagnostics would be helpful so I can figure out what the problem actually is.
